# Is there anyway to run this command automatically when system boots up

Tags: boot, virtualization, startup, automation, source

Everytime I run my ubuntu VM I have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` I was wondering if there's any way which would run this command automatically as soon as I boot my VM up without me having to do this every single time.

Comment: when you say you run ubuntu VM, does this mean you are starting that instant from start or you are using saved state option of virtualbox/vmware? Also, do you mind sharing what command you are trying to run from bash_profile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Answer (score 0):

> **What is a login or non-login shell?**
>
> When you login (type username and password) via console, either
>   sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: .bash_profile is executed
>   to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.
>
> But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new
>   terminal window (xterm) inside Gnome or KDE, then .bashrc is executed
>   before the window command prompt. .bashrc is also run when you start a
>   new bash instance by typing /bin/bash in a terminal.
>
> **Why two different files?**
>
> Say, you’d like to print some lengthy diagnostic information about
>   your machine each time you login (load average, memory usage, current
>   users, etc). You only want to see it on login, so you only want to
>   place this in your .bash_profile. If you put it in your .bashrc, you’d
>   see it every time you open a new terminal window.

That was an excerpt from a blog post that might help you. [.bash_profile vs .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

Comment: Just read the differences, you mean I should add content of bash_profile into bashrc?

Comment: Ye try that. The .bashrc file should already be there.

Answer (score 0):

save a cmd.sh with command  you want to run.

sudo chmod +x cmd.sh

sudo crontab -e

enter the below line at end of file

@reboot path_to_your_file/cmd.sh

save and exit.

warning @reboot is a non standard syntex old crontab will fail.